# Restoring positions and sizes of windows after undocking a laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop which docks or plugs into 2 large monitors at my desk. When I unplug my laptop, to go to a meeting, it moves all the program windows onto the small laptop screen. Then when I plug it back in at my desk I have to rearrange all the windows again back onto the large monitors.

Is there a way I can keep all the windows positioning? Can you use the desktop feature in Windows to help one do this?

Comment: Note: other similar questions exist on Superuser but not specifically for Windows 10

Comment: How does Windows 10 invalidate those existing answers?